# I shared my property on facebook and when is clicked url

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url

I share on facebook this content from my wordpress site :

http://nekretninemiletic.co.rs/ponuda/stan-promenada-vrnjacka-banja/

and when is clicked on facebook, url is :

http://nekretninemiletic.co.rs/ponuda/stan-promenada-vrnjacka-banja/#.U9PQKP5NAKY.facebook

How can I get rid of this " #.U9PQKP5NAKY.facebook " . It causes me a problem.Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tracking code from your AddThis plugin. Apparently this can be removed. [Method here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1013558-removing-all-hashtags-anchors-weird-codes-from-your-urls). Not sure if it removing it will break your tracking or not.